# react-native with healthkit api

Tags: react-native, healthkit

enter image description hereI got the problem with an npm package that is rn-apple-healthkit.
And my problem is as a below
https://github.com/terrillo/rn-apple-healthkit/issues/16

### I have imported AppleHealthkit, however Eslint still alert me AppleHealthkit is not defined in "***AppleHealthkit.initStepCountObserver({}, () => {});***"

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  Navigator,
  View,
  NativeAppEventEmitter,
} from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import AppleHealthKit from 'rn-apple-healthkit';

import AlbumDetail from './AlbumDetail';

// Healthkit API part
const d = new Date();

const PERMS = AppleHealthKit.Constants.Permissions;

const HKOPTIONS = {
  permissions: {
    read: [
        PERMS.StepCount,
        PERMS.Height,
        PERMS.Weight,
        PERMS.DateOfBirth,
        PERMS.BodyMassIndex,
    ],
    write: [
        PERMS.StepCount,
        PERMS.Weight,
        PERMS.BodyMassIndex,
    ],
  },
  date: d.toISOString()
};

AppleHealthKit.initHealthKit(HKOPTIONS, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('HealthkitInitError: ', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('HealthkitInitSucess');

  AppleHealthkit.initStepCountObserver({}, () => {});

  this.sub = NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener(
    'change:steps',
    (event) => {
    //'change:steps' event has been received. step
    //count data should be re-fetched from Healthkit.
      this._fetchStepCountData();
      console.log(event);
    }
  );
  this._fetchStepCountData();
  this._fetchOtherRelevantHealthkitData();
});

// StepCounter Example
AppleHealthKit.getStepCount(HKOPTIONS, (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log('getStepCountError: ', error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(results);
});

// React-Native part
class albumList extends Component {
  state = { albums: [] };
  
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
      .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }))
      .then(response => console.log(response));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.albums);
  }

// when the component where the listener was added unmounts, call the 'remove' method of the subscription object.
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.sub.remove();
  };

  renderAlbums() {
    return this.state.albums.map(album => 
      <AlbumDetail key={album.title} data={album} />
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView> 
        {this.renderAlbums()}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default albumList;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXZzD.jpg)

Comment: `AppleHealthkit.initStepCountObserver({}, () => {});` should be `AppleHealthKit.initStepCountObserver({}, () => {});` with capital `K`

Comment: Thanks for your reply:)
I got a new problm!! 
Are you have any idea?
The mistake:
_this._fetchStepCountData is not a function